# std::fill segmentation fault error when the array is large

Tags: c++, arrays, fill

I have the following class which resembles a scalar field in two dimensions, but since periodic boundary conditions may be used, there are also ghost zones (simply view this as a 2D matrix).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>

class RectMesh
{
private:

  int cols_x;
  int rows_y;
  int nghost;
  double* mesh;

public:

  void CheckConstr(int& cols, int& rows, int& ghost);
  RectMesh(int cols=2, int rows=2, int ghost=1);

  /* Rule of 5 */
  ~RectMesh();
  RectMesh(const RectMesh& obj);
  RectMesh(RectMesh&& tmp) noexcept;
  RectMesh& operator=(RectMesh rhs);
  RectMesh& operator=(RectMesh&& tmp);
  
};
```

The constructor implementation is

```
/*--------------------- Constructor -----------------------------*/
void RectMesh::CheckConstr(int& cols, int& rows, int& ghost)
{
  if (cols < 2 || rows < 2 || ghost < 0)
    {
      std::cout << "The smallest mesh must have dimensions (2x2)"
    "and the minimum number of ghost points is zero. Exiting."
        << std::endl; 
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

RectMesh::RectMesh(int cols, int rows, int ghost)
  : cols_x(cols), rows_y(rows), nghost(ghost), mesh(nullptr)
{
  CheckConstr(cols,rows,ghost);
  int len = (cols_x+2*nghost)*(rows_y + 2*nghost);
  mesh = (double*) fftw_malloc(len*sizeof(double));
  std::fill(mesh, mesh+len, 0.0);
  std::cout << "RectMesh constructor called." << std::endl;
}
```

Main function

```
int main()
{
  int cols = 1e6;
  int rows = 1e6;
  int nghost = 2;
  RectMesh A(cols,rows,nghost);
  return 0;
}
```

Console output:
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

This doesn't happen when I comment out the `std::fill` or when I have `rows = cols = 1e5`.

Why is that?

Comment: fit 1e6 * 1e6 * 4 bytes to your memory?

Comment: `(log (coerce (* 8 1000000 1000000) 'float) 2.0)
42.863136` On 32 bit systems, another reason for trouble would be that your int would need 43 bits for len.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int len = (cols_x+2*nghost)*(rows_y + 2*nghost);
```

Plugging in 1e6 for `cols_x` and `rows_y`, and 2 for `nghost`, and then multiplying the end result by `sizeof(double)` which is 8, the grand total is:

```
8000064000128
```

bytes, or over seven terabytes of memory you're trying to allocate. One of two things are happening here:

1. `fftw_malloc` has a big laugh about it, and returns `NULL`, and your shown code fails to check its return value, and discover that nothing was allocated, or
2. The actual multiplication overflows (if on a 32 bit platform), with similarly absurd results.

Comment: I guess the second can be prevented if I use size_t?

Comment: If `size_t` is a 64 bit `long long`, on a 32 bit platform, then yes. But, with these parameters, you still need to find room to put a few terabytes of RAM chips in your computer, whether you use `size_t` or not.

Comment: sure, thanks for the answer. I also edit my post with the solution.

Comment: @Angelos please don't edit answers into your question, you can add your own answer if you feel you need to add something to the existing answers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running a common or typical computer, a 1e6 columns by 1e6 rows of `double`s are, well

> 1000000 * 1000000 * 8 bytes = 8 TB (or 7.28 TiB)

So the answer is: Check the return value of `fftw_malloc`, which you didn't. Chances are **it failed and returned a null pointer**, which is surely going to cause a mess when you try to access it.

Also, check the results of the multiplication. `int` is most likely 4-byte and doesn't hold such a value (some 43-bit integer). Switch to `size_t` instead.

---

If you reduce the dimensions to 1e5 each, the result would be 80 GB (74.51 GiB) which may fit in large servers.